# Search for a specific field in all folders. MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a field called "last_updated" in the database amongst all of those folders. I'm wondering if it is possible to search for that specific field in all those folders

[image]

Comment: It can't be done in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

If by "folders" you mean "collections" , this is what you can do:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collname) {
  var count = db[collname].find({"last_update": {$exists: true}}).limit(1);
  if (count > 0) {
  print(collname);
}
})
```

As a result you will have all collection names where you have at least one document having last_update field present.